# ggplot2 Boxplot displays different median than calculated

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, boxplot, median

I'm plotting a simple boxplot of two group's weight by year based on big data (2150000 cases). 
All groups have the same median except for the last group in the last year but on the boxplot, it is drawn like it is the same as every other.

```
 #boxplot
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=Year, y=SUM_MME_mg, fill=GenderPerson)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)+
  ylim(0,850)


#median by group
pivot <- dataset %>%
  select(SUM_MME_mg,GenderPerson,Year )%>%
  group_by(Year, GenderPerson) %>%
  summarise(MedianValues = median(SUM_MME_mg,na.rm=TRUE))
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong or which data is more accurate in boxplot calculations or median function. R returns no error or warning.

```
 #my data:
> dput(head(dataset[,c(1,7,10)]))
structure(list(GenderPerson = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Year = c("2015", 
"2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2015"), SUM_MME_mg = c(416.16, 
131.76, 790.56, 878.4, 878.4, 878.4)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is linked to how `ylim()` operates.  `ylim()` is a convenience function/wrapper for `scale_y_continuous(limits=...`.  If you [look into the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.3.0/topics/scale_continuous) for the `scale_continuous` functions, you'll see that setting limits does not just zoom in on an area, but in fact *removes all datapoints outside that area as well*.  This happens before the computation/stat functions, so this is why the median is different when you use `ylim()`.  Your calculation "outside" `ggplot()` is taking the entire dataset, whereas the use of `ylim()` means that datapoints are removed before the calculation is made.

Luckily, there's a simple fix for that, which is to use `coord_cartesian(ylim=...)` in place of `ylim()`, since `coord_cartesian()` will simply zoom in on the data without removing datapoints.  See the difference here:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=Year, y=SUM_MME_mg, fill=GenderPerson)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + ylim(0,850)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=Year, y=SUM_MME_mg, fill=GenderPerson)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,850))
```

[image]

The hint for this behavior should also be evident in that the first code chunk using `ylim()` should also give you a warning message:

```
Warning message:
Removed 3 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
```

Whereas the second using `coord_cartesian(ylim=` does not.

Comment: Thank you that really helped a lot.

Comment: Thank you! This issue was also very difficult to trace in my case.